# Is this a real check?

Tags: personal-check

I was recently given a personal check that had only the routing number on the bottom but no account number. There appears to be a number in the top left corner that could be it. Can i cash this check?

Comment: That sounds atypical, but do you have any reason other than the check appearance to suspect it's not valid?

Comment: From someone you know? For an amount you expected?

Comment: Why not going to the bank, and ask them? Probadly they will know what the legal matter, and you shouldn't be afraid of getting jailed when you ask if it is a regular check. And you can get your money there too ;)

Comment: Is the check a cashiers check? does the check have the writers address?

Comment: Could it be a temporary check? Can you describe the appearance of the check overall?

Answer (score 2):

Your bank is the entity who could determine if the check is real or not.  Bear in mind that it is [check kiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_kiting) (a form of check fraud) to knowing cash a perfectly legitimate check from a bank if the check writer doesn't have sufficient funds to cover the check amount.